# R data.table syntax for subsetting and summarising

Tags: r, data.table

This is probablly quite simple but would like to be able to summarise some data (mean and median) based upon on random column selection, and for it to be grouped by a different column.

Please see below:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
ww <- sample(c("y","v"),1)
DT[,list(avg=mean(ww),med=median(ww)),by="x"]
   x avg med
1: a  NA   y
2: b  NA   y
3: c  NA   y
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(DT, , list(avg = mean(ww), med = median(ww)),  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In `[.data.table`(DT, , list(avg = mean(ww), med = median(ww)),  :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In `[.data.table`(DT, , list(avg = mean(ww), med = median(ww)),  :
 argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

If for example ww happened to equal `"v"` then I would expect the following output

```
   x avg med
1: a   2   2  
2: b   5   5
3: c   8   8
```

I think it is just syntax that I need to adjust, but am unsure how to adjust it...Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Here's another way to do it: `DT[,lapply(list(avg=mean,med=median),function(f)f(.SD[[ww]])),by="x"]` or with `get`, as described in the answer below...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `get`:

```
> DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
> ww <- sample(c("y","v"),1)
> DT[,list(avg=mean(get(ww)),med=median(get(ww))),by="x"]
   x      avg med
1: a 3.333333   3
2: b 3.333333   3
3: c 3.333333   3
> ww
[1] "y"
```

Comment: Ah! I knew it was simple!

Comment: @h.l.m, it would be nicer if `data.table` gave a more descriptive error message in this case.

Comment: I've heard it's slow, but `.SD[[ww]]` also works: `DT[,list(avg=mean(.SD[[ww]]),med=median(.SD[[ww]])),by="x"]`

Comment: +1 If the dynamism is needed to fast then an `eval`+`parse` solution should be fastest, similar to a dynamic query in SQL. Use of `get` in `j` triggers full `.SD` subsetting (same as use of `.SD`) because it's difficult for `data.table` to establish reliably which columns are really needed by `j` in this case. If `DT` has many columns (say 50+) and only a few are picked out by `get` then for speed don't use `get` (use `eval` and `parse` instead to allow `data.table` optimisation to work).  Use `verbose=TRUE` to reveal what happens.